# Why doesnt this switch work with my onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I am changing a variable based on the value selected from a dropdown.  I have something similar working with an if/else statement but when I try it with switch I can not get it to work.  I made [a fiddle of this](http://jsfiddle.net/agXQL/1/) here

html :

```
<select class="heiSelect">
            <option value='3924'>6'1"</option>
            <option value='3923'>6'2"</option>
            <option value='3922'>6'3"</option>
            <option value='3921'>6'4"</option>
            <option value='3920'>6'5"</option>
            <option value='3919'>6'6"</option>
            <option value='3918'>6'7"</option>
            <option value='3917'>6'8"</option>
            <option value='3916'>6'9"</option>
            <option value='3915'>6'10"</option>
     </select>
<h1>Results : </h1>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var hvd = 0;
    $('.heiSelect').change(function() {
        var heiValue = $('.heiSelect').val();
        switch (heiValue) {
        case 3915:
            hvd = 4294964526;
            break;
        case 3916:
            hvd = 4294964528;
            break;
        case 3917:
            hvd = 4294964529;
            break;
        case 3918:
            hvd = 4294964406;
            break;
        case 3919:
            hvd = 4294964495;
            break;
        case 3920:
            hvd = 4294964494;
            break;
        case 3921:
            hvd = 4294964493;
            break;
        case 3922:
            hvd = 4294964492;
            break;
        case 3923:
            hvd = 4294964491;
            break;
        case 3924:
            hvd = 4294964490;
            break;
        }
        $('h1').append(heiValue + " + " + hvd + ", ");

    });
});
```

Can you see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is a string, while you tested them against numbers.

To fix it, either parse the string into integer:

```
var heiValue = parseInt($('.heiSelect').val(), 10);
```

or use strings in the cases:

```
case '3915':
```

Answer (score 0):

`heiValue` is a string, which you are comparing to integers in your `switch` statement.

Either parse `heiValue` into an integer, or convert your case statements to strings.